# With `ls -sh` is 1K a kilobyte, a kilobit, 1000 bytes, 1024 bytes, or what?

Tags: linux, bash, ls, size

Preface to my question (this isn't my question):
I've been looking for a command-line tool to that tells me how many bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, etc. that a file is (not some other form of measurement).

Question:
I found that `ls -sh` outputs filesize, but it just uses K, M, G and such as the measurement. So, it seems ambiguous. What does this actually mean? The manpage for ls also talks about blocks and stuff in relation to filesize, and I don't know how, or even if, that relates to kilobytes and kilobits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU Coreutils `ls` manual page says:

> `-h, --human-readable`
>
> with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.
>
> `--si`
>
> likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024

So `-h` must be using powers of 1024, otherwise the `--si` option wouldn't be described this way.